# iOS: Appending an uneditable string to the end of a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I would like to reproduce a screen similar to the Facebook "Update Status" view in iOS.

[image]
[image]

(This text should be editable) Walking (Anything past here should not be editable) - at South Narrabeen Beach

The user should be able to enter/edit text to the left of the appended string. The appended string will need to wrap within its parent and be clickable.

Does anyone know how this is done? (I have recently seen it in the Viddy app as well).

Could it be a growing UITextField with a UIAttributedString split over 2 lines that updates its frame as the text is entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
It looks like what you want is to let the user place the cursor in the signature anyway, but not let her type
In that case, you would want to use this instead

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
   NSInteger signatureLength=20;
   if(range.location>self.textView.text.length-signatureLength){
       return false;
   }
   else{
       return true;
   }
}
```

**Original:**

You need to use UITextViewDelegate

Implement the - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView method, something like:

For this example, let's assume the signature length is 20, this would look something like this:

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
       NSInteger signatureLength=20;
       NSRange newSelection=self.textView.selectedRange;
       if(newSelection.location>self.textView.text.length-signatureLength){
           [self.textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(self.textView.text.length-signatureLength, 0)];
       }
 }
```

So basically you intercept every time the selection (== the cursor in this case) changes, and if the cursor is going to be in the middle of the signature, you reposition it just before.
Setting a selection with a 0 length just changes the cursor position.

Comment: Just a precision, the assumption is that you init the textview with a signature string, and that in this case the signature length is 20 characters.

Comment: With this method how would you format and make the signature string clickable?

Comment: What do you mean? Clickable as you want the cursor to blink within it? but just not editable?  Then you should use - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text    instead, let me edit my answer with that info

Comment: By clickable I mean tappable, e.g. like the Facebook app, when you select a place it is added to the right of the hyphen and is uneditable but you can tap on it to change it.

Comment: Hi JP, the textViewDidChangeSelection is on the right track. The signature will be dynamic (which shouldn't be a problem). I just need to be able to format it and make it tappable like a uibutton

Comment: I think what confuses me is the "uneditable"... "but you can change it", it seems to be contradictory. But in any case, the idea is to either use textViewDidChangeSelection  if you want to interecept after the tap but before typing anything, or shouldChangeTextInRange  if you want to intercept whenever to validate or not an edition. You can perform any operation you like in there

Comment: Thanks JP, not exactly what I was looking for but textViewDidChangeSelection helps me along the way so I will accept your answer. Check out how the Facebook app works when tagging friends or places and you will see what I meant. Thanks for your help.