# How to make part of UITextView uneditable and clickable, with properly shown emojis?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextview, emoji

I have `UITextView` in my app, and it should contain an **uneditable and clickable** suffix (categoryString), something like [Facebook 'feeling, watching, eating,...' status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263919/ios-appending-an-uneditable-string-to-the-end-of-a-uitextview). My `shouldChangeTextInRange` and `textViewDidChange` methods look like this:

```
    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.globalInt, 0)

               //On long press backspace, something goes wrong with
               //NSMutableAttributedString, so I just clear textView
               //and set it's text to categoryString again:

                if(!textView.text.hasSuffix(self.categoryString)){

                    self.globalInt = 0

                    self.postTextView.font = Constants.Fonts.postTextCategory
                    textView.text = self.categoryString
                    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0,0)

                }
            })


            self.myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.postTextView.text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:Constants.Fonts.postTextCategory!])
            self.myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: Constants.Fonts.postText!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: maxGlobalInt))
            self.postTextView.attributedText = self.myMutableString

        }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

            var tempText : NSString = text
            var currentText : NSString = textView.text

            var textToReturn = currentText.length + (tempText.length - range.length)

            if(text == "\n"){
                textView.resignFirstResponder()
            }

            var signatureLength = count(categoryString)

            globalInt = textToReturn - signatureLength
            maxGlobalInt = textToReturn - signatureLength

            if(range.location >  textToReturn - signatureLength){
                return false
            }else{

                return textToReturn <= 160 + signatureLength
            }

        }
```

`UITextView` font is bold by default, so I use `NSMutableAttributedString` to change font for editable part of `UITextView` (you can see that in `textViewDidChange`).

**FIRST PROBLEM:** When I edit `UITextView`, and want to set cursor somewhere in the middle of text, I can type only one character (even backspace) and then cursor automatically move to ending position of editable part of text. If I add these lines of code to `shouldChangeTextInRange`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.globalInt = range.location + 1

        if(count(text) == 0){
            self.globalInt = self.globalInt - 1
        }else{
            self.globalInt = range.location + 1
        }
    })
```

that solves my problem, cursor position is always ok, but I have a new one - emoji characters don't show properly:

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

I assume that's happening because emoji character length, but I don't have any idea how to solve this?

**SECOND PROBLEM:** How to make uneditable part of `UITextView` clickable? (Instead of setting cursor there)

Comment: you can use UITapGestureRecogniser

Comment: have you check UITextField leftView and rightView properties? using that we can set left side or ride side images for that.

Comment: Read the question, he's using a UITextView, which doesn't have leftView/rightView properties.